# Failure to enter the while loop even when the condition is true

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I am working to extract the data from database. Please find the code below:

I am using "org.springframework.jdbc.support.rowset.SqlRowSet" from Springframework.jdbc.

```
String query="SELECT * from TABLE_NAME where id=? and password=?";
args.add(userId);
args.add(password);
SqlRowSet rs = this.jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(query, args.toArray());
while (rs.next()) {
---Some Code---
}
```

rs.next() is true, but it is not going into the loop. Need some help on how to overcome this issue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't make sense, what make you sure that rs.next() is returning true?

Comment: What is `SqlRowSet`?

Comment: While debugging the code I found out that the value is true but not entering ino the loop. @elkorchianas

Comment: @Pshemo its a class in "org.springframework.jdbc.support.rowset"

Comment: If the loop isn't executing, and you know for sure that the loop is not, then no matter what you think, re.next() is not returning true. It's that straight forward.

Comment: You should put information about libraries/frameworks you are using in your question to avoid confusion. Also code you posted seems to be working fine. If `rs.next()` returns `true` then by design Java must enter in loop. What makes you think that it doesn't? If you want to get proper answer consider posting [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) / [MCVE]

Comment: @elkorchianas tried your suggestion. But its not working out. Same result :(

Comment: @Pshemo Sorry for not providing the library/framework before. Next time I will make sure I will post al the necessary information. But I am pretty sure that the condition is true but the code inside the loop is not executing. Just want to know if some one faced this before.

Comment: You still can update your question and provide all necessary info. Simply use [edit] option.

Comment: @elkorchianas rs.next() returns a Boolean and can not be compared with null..need some serious help :(

Comment: "*But I am pretty sure that the condition is true but the code inside the loop is not executing.*" that would mean you found bug in Java which wasn't yet discovered in its very long life. Something is telling me that it is less probable than that your assumptions ware wrong. Make sure that `rs.next()` is infact returning true, also you need to specify what exactly you are doing inside that loop. If it is some DB manipulation then maybe you need to commit your changes.

Comment: And make sure rs.next() returns a Boolean.  It could be that it's returning an object (which is non-zero which some languages consider to be "true") and the method you really want is something like rs.hasNext()

Answer (score 3):

This is just a guess, but since you know that `rs.next()` returns `true`, it means you executed it (either in debug mode or printed to console or whatever).

Every time you execute it, it advances the rowset to the next row, if there is one. If your rowset contains only 1 row, and you "check" the value returned by `rs.next()` before the loop, the loop will never be entered because when it's called again there are no more rows, so it returns `false`.

Comment: This is almost certainly the answer. There's no other way OP could have determined it returned true, since it supposedly didn't enter the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't the reason for that. But I have changed the implementation. I have changed the while loop to for loop by getting the size from the resultSet. Thanks a lot for your suggestions.

```
int size =0;  
            if (rs != null)   
            {  
                rs.beforeFirst();  
                rs.last();  
            size = rs.getRow();
            }
            for (int i =0;i<size;i++){//Do SOMETHING}
```